# shower stem replacement troubleshooting.

Tags: plumbing, troubleshooting

I replaced the hot water stem, went to HOME DEPOT and got a replacement. Price Pfizer is the brand according to the HD advisor. However I was wondering if you know or are aware of any tricks with it. As soon as I installed the new one and tested there was no water coming into the shower head, nor hot or cold ? What? yes I asked myself too. So I tested to make sure there was no debris in the line or anything plugging the line, I removed the new hot stem valve and open the cold water and there was water shooting out from the open side, I did the same with the hot water opened the valve on the water heater and there was water coming too. Went back to Home Depot and I had 3 advisors working with me since they never had that situation. Since nobody had a solution they gave a new stem in case it was a bad one. I know it can’t be very high tech. it’s mechanical and very stray forward but still can not make water come out of the head shower, by the way there’s is hot and cold water working out of the faucet sink in the same bathroom and  the rest of the house…..

Comment: Does the stem appear identical to the one you pulled out?
Is there an orientation issue?  E.g. You are inserting in 180 degrees out of phase?  Does putting the old one back in work?  (At least as badly as it did before.)  Get out measuring tools and check that they are identical, and that you didn't get one with the holes 3/8 of an inch too close to one end.

Comment: I have a 2-handle Price Pfister mixing valve in the tub/shower combo and in a shower. (Mine is the old type with no thermostatic or pressure balancing.) Both are original and work fine. These go from shut to full on with about one quarter turn. I also think there must be an orientation problem with the way you are installing it so it is never opening, but in my experience these parts are designed with a "key" to only go in one way. Have you carefully examined the new part and compared it to the old one?